# jQuery count checked checkbox in next element

Tags: jquery, forms, count, jquery-selectors

My sample is counting every single checkbox on a page. **How to count the checked checkboxes on next/sibling element with jQuery?**

PS: I want this to work on multiple forms on a single page without calling the element(form) ID.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countChecked() {
    var tCount = $("input:checked").length;
      $(".totalchecked").text( tCount + ' selected');
  }
  countChecked();
  var tCheck = $(".totalchecked");
  $(tCheck).next().find(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>form 1:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="3">
  </div>
</div>
<div>form 2:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="4">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="5">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="6">
  </div>
</div>
```

**/* Update */** 
I want something like this. 
[image]

Comment: Please make sure, your question is should clear and understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this working sample:

```js
function checkTotalCheckedBoxes(){
$("div" ).each(function( ) {
  if(this.children.length === 3){ 
  var checked = 0;
 $(this.children).each(function() {
        this.checked ? checked++ : null;      
        $("input[name="+this.name+"]").parent().siblings().closest('.totalchecked')[0].innerText = (checked) + " selected"; 

       });
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>form 1:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
<input type="checkbox" class="class" name="1"  onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
<input type="checkbox" class="class" name="2"  onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
<input type="checkbox" class="class" name="3"  onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
  </div>
</div>
<div>form 2:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
<input type="checkbox" class="class" name="4"  onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
<input type="checkbox" class="class" name="5"  onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
<input type="checkbox" class="class" name="6"  onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. Each "(.totalchecked)" should only count the checked checkboxes on next/siblings element.

Comment: Is is possible to add id or class name for any of div forms? it would be easier to identified specific form by that?@CocoSkin

Comment: The idea is not to call the element ID. I use this on a CMS plugin.

Comment: @CocoSkin please run the sample now. I did some js update I hope this basic sample is good enough for you, so you can update more for your needs.

Comment: The sample you have is counted per click not per checked checkbox.

Comment: @CocoSkin this version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180678/discussion-between-cocoskin-and-nezir).

Comment: This is great. I would update the script to be more like this.
function checkTotalCheckedBoxes(){
    $(".totalchecked + div" ).each(function() {
      var checked = 0;
        $(this.children).each(function() {
            this.checked ? checked++ : null;      
            $("input[name="+this.name+"]").parent().siblings().closest('.totalchecked')[0].innerText = (checked) + " selected"; 
        });
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        var siblingsChecked = [];
           $(this).siblings().each(function(el){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    siblingsChecked.push(el);
                }
          });
        console.log(siblingsChecked.length);
    });
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution and I hope it helps someone.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $SelectCount = $("input:checkbox")
    $SelectCount.change(function(){
        var countChecked = $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").filter(':checked').length;
        $(this).parent().siblings(".totalchecked").text(countChecked + " Selected");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>form 1:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="3">
  </div>
</div>
<div>form 2:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="4">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="5">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countChecked() {
    var tCount = $("input:checked").length;
      $(".totalchecked").text( tCount + ' selected');
  }
  countChecked();
  var tCheck = $(".totalchecked");
  $(tCheck).next().find(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>form 1:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="3">
  </div>
</div>
<div>form 2:
  <div class="totalchecked">0 selected</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="4">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="5">
    <input type="checkbox" class="class" name="6">
  </div>
</div>
```